# mat-table - centered text would rather overflow than move towards top

Tags: css, angular, vertical-alignment, mat-table

Currently, I have a mat-table with Angular.
All the content is centered. Before switching to `ng-container` with `mat-table`, relatively simple CSS allowed for the text contents of one column with longer contents to be centered vertically.

Older, straightforward, working CSS:

```
padding: 1rem 1rem;
vertical-align: middle;
align-items: center;
justify-items: center;
text-align: center;
```

I tried duplicating that in
`td.mat-row-cell` without success i.e.

```
td.mat-row-cell {
height: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
max-height: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
align-items: center;
justify-items: center;
text-align: center;
}
```

So I tried targeting the column more specifically, by adding:

```
td.mat-column-example {
min-width: 125px; 
width: 125px;
max-width: 125px !important;
height: 50px;
max-height: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

without success.
Consequently, I tried adding the inline style option:

```
style="justify-content: safe"
```

as it sounded most appropriate. But it also didn't help.

Comment: One thing I dislike a great deal about material: you usually have to override them in the styles.css more often than not. I'd try that and ensure your styles are getting applied.

Comment: When I moved from half-moon with tables to ng-container it seemed that mat-table was going to fix/simplify everything. It worked as expected in Chrome and Edge. All the examples I've seen make this work with relatively simple CSS and relatively simple tables. I haven't found a solution per se a much as a workaround using Angular methods.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is more of a workaround. Setting every possible parent element's padding and margins to 0 helped a little. However, longer text still does not center vertically where its center is the center line. Consequently, I wrote a workaround using `ngStyle`.
Basically, if the text exceeds the length needed to but max-height, the alignment is top. For more customization, I call a method rather than just set the style inline.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let example" style="max-height: 50px;" [ngStyle]="checkLength(example.text.length)"> {{example.text}} </td>
```

and the corresponding function in the app component example.component.ts is:

```
checkLength(length): Record<string, unknown> {
  if (length > 100) { 
    return {'vertical-align': 'top', 'text-align': 'top'};
    }
  return {};
  }
```